# How to crawl face image using google image search engine?

Tags: image-processing, web-crawler, google-search-api

I need some face image data for training. I want to collect them from the Internet. I have tried [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/). But it seems not work now (officially deprecated).

Is there any other method for crawling image from google. From other search engine is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Custom Search JSON API for this.

1. Go to google.com/cse
2. Create an engine with any url
3. In the sidebar go to Edit search engine > Setup
4. Delete your url, enable image search, enable "Search entire web..."

Now if you search for "face", in the image tab you get pics of faces from the internet. To learn how to use this programmatically from JSON API, check Developer's guide:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview